# Android webview unable to play videos other than mp4 format

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating Webview intent with the link of a video url.
But currently only mp4 videos play inside the webview, other formats (flv, mkv,etc) videos just display blank screen

Here is the android studio logcat when I open the webview:

```
W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 4 for video/hevc
W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
```

Here are the webview settings:

```java
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, no one replied to this question. I went on with the exomedia library, instead of the webview.